# What is the total number of distinct $m\times n$ matrices in row canonical form using only $0$s and $1$s?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix over a field $F$. What is the total number $N$ of the distinct matrices in row-reduced echelon form that are row equivalent to $A$ and that only have entires either $0$s or $1$s?

I know that this number $N$ is $5$ if $A$ is $2 \times 2$, and that $N$ is 16 if $A$ is $3\times 3$. Am I right?

Can a general formula be obtained?

We can assume without any loss of generality that $F$ is the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers. Am I right?

Comment: I really don't think you meant "that are row equivalent to $A$".  For example, there is no matrix with entries in $\{0,1\}$ that is row equivalent to $\pmatrix{1 & \pi \cr 0 & 0\cr}$.

Answer (score 1):

An $m \times n$ matrix of rank $k$ in RREF will have $k$ leading ones, which can be in any $k$ of the $n$ columns.  There are ${n \choose k}$ ways to choose these if $0 \le k \le \min(m,n)$.  Suppose those are columns $j_1 < j_2 < \ldots <  j_k$.  In row $i$ (for $i \le k$) we have $n - j_i - (k-i)$ "free" positions where there can be either $0$ or $1$.
Thus for a given choice of $j_1, \ldots, j_k$ there are a total of $M = nk + \frac{k-k^2}{2} - \sum_{i=1}^k j_i$ free positions, and this corresponds to $2^M$ of those matrices.

Hmm: it looks to me like in the case $m\ge n$ this is [OEIS sequence A006116](https://oeis.org/A006116).